# Lubuntu 16.04 - Firefox not working

Tags: lubuntu, firefox

I have this issue being novice in Lubuntu. I cannot access Internet because Firefox keeps on telling me this: ''Your connection is not secure''. It shows two icons - Go back - Advanced.

I have not changed any settings in Lubuntu, just installed this OS from scratch.

What do I do to browse Internet?

Comment: Is your lubuntu up to date? Did your try to access with another browser (ex: chromium) and got same error? Please open your firefox, clear your cache, cookies and open sessions.  Then, try to access a site and after you got the error, open your console  (pressing `ctrl`+`shift`+`j`) and list the messages in your question.

Comment: Another issues:  Does all public sites you return this messages? Did you access Internet directly or through a proxy or by a provider interface? If yes, did you try to access through other network?

Comment: It’s always a good idea to install several browsers even if you don't intend using all of them. I can tell you from my own experience that this simple measure can help you a lot. Try several browsers. If you still encounter this problem, then there is something wrong with the connection. Otherwise, you just have a faulty browser.

Comment: Sure @CristianaNicolae. I have three: firefox, chromium and opera. Occasionally, any site doesn't load ok on one browser, but works fine on another. I suggest use chromium instead chrome. This last steal a lot of memory.